# ClassVar.prefab not showing in inspector in Unity

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I am working on a "Shoot a ball into bin" game. I am trying to get a prefab object (via inspector) then instantiate it but then stumbled upon this problem when the inspector doesn't show a prefab option to input the prefab GameObject even though this code:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class Obj
{
    public GameObject prefab;
}
```

Should do just that.

Full code:

```cs
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour 
{
   [System.Serializable]
    public class Obj
    {
        public GameObject prefab; // Get Prefab from Inspector
    }
    
    void Update() 
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            Obj obj = new Obj();

            Instantiate(obj.prefab, playerBody); // playerbody is a Transform
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has a solution to this problem, please tell me.
It will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not the `Full code` .. otherwise it wouldn't even compile ;)

---

As it stands

You defined a class, yes, **but** I don't see any field in your class actually using your type!

It should probably be e.g.

```
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Obj
    {
        public GameObject prefab;
    }

    public Obj obj;
    // Or also
    //[SerializeField] private Obj obj;

    // Wherever you get this from
    Transform playerBody;
    
    void Update() 
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            Instantiate(obj.prefab, playerBody);
        }
    }
}
```

In particular note that if you do

```
Obj obj = new Obj();
```

inside this just newly created `Obj` Instance the `prefab` would of course be unassigned.

---

My question would be though: Is this really all your `Obj` class does? Because in such case why not rather simply have

```
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    // Or also
    //[SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;

    // Wherever you get this from
    Transform playerBody;
    
    void Update() 
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            Instantiate(prefab, playerBody);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes things so much easier. Thank you @derHugo!

Comment: I think that I may have been overcomplicated the code XD